# Downloadable Image or PDF created from div data

Tags: javascript, pdf, html, php, web

I am building a website where a user can add data to a  element on the HTML page. The data will consist of images and text. I am wondering if there is a way that I can export this data to a PDF or image format and allow the user to download it. Maybe a library? The website is using Javascript, PHP, HTML and CSS currently. I would love to be able to format the PDF to look a certain way as well. One of the most important things is that this software is usable by all modern browsers.

Comment: There are PDF libraries for PHP, e.g. TCPDF, which let you generate PDF documents. Would that be what you're looking for?

Comment: Glad to read! If it fits, maybe you want to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this I ended up using DOMPDF (https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) which allowed me to write CSS and HTML to a PDF object in PHP and present this to the user. DOMPDF facilitates many of the CSS options that other HTML to PDF software doesn't.